# ngrx/store container components - use store directly ? or facade?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

while implementing an ngrx/store solution, 
i'm creating smart/container component. 
i am reading some conflicting ideas in some blogs.

should the smart component inject the store  ? or should i create a service that will be a facade, in the service will inject the store ?

While the idea of using a service to "hide" the store itself is nice, it seems that it make some code duplicate.
for example, if in the component i need to dispatch an action "ADD_USER" i will call a function in the service named: addUserAction(user) and in the service, i will have a one liner function: store.dispatch({type: ADD_USER, payload: user})

thanks !

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: why you need teamviewer ?

Comment: thanks for your offer, but i just need general guidance as for best practice...

Comment: Sure. but your post to broad.

Comment: i tried to be clear. on q1: do you introduce the store to your component , or using a facade

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893676/ngxs-call-an-angular-service-good-practices/

Answer (score 1):

If your facade layer is just a thin wrapper over store.select then it's probably not worth the trouble.  I would only introduce the facade layer when it needs to manage a bunch of services as explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern